# What's The Easiest Way To Maintain Remote Users Access to a Webapp

Tags: authentication, access-control, vpn

Here is a real world case:

A chain of high schools (several hundreds) has many websites (~ 3x number of Schools) that are content driven by users (the students).

Every school maintains about 2-4 websites, and the total number of sites reaches few thousands.

They want to limit access to the sites to students only.
Given students are likely to connect from homes which means their IP address varies every time, I thought the best will be to limit the access to a pre-defined school's addresses range, and let students login via VPN into the school specific network - one which will be allowed at the web farm.

Given we are dealing with education institution, open source / free solutions are the only way to go.

Question is, whether there are tools which are going to ease the maintenance of this setup.

Also, if anyone can come up with other solutions which requires no special hardware (i.e. tokens, etc.) I would be glad to hear (perhaps mutual authentication with client certs is also a way to go).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Wouldn't a reverse proxy match also this need and be lightweight than setting up a VPN (unless there is already a VPN available for the students and serving other purposes) ?